# Proper way to fix a url without http://

Tags: python, url, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to `open` a list of urls of this format, using in `Urllib2`:

```
google.com
facebook.com
youtube.com
yahoo.com
baidu.com
```

Using this method:

`urllib2.urlopen(url)`:

And getting this error:

```
File "fetcher.py", line 98, in fetch_urls_and_save
  response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
File "urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "urllib2.py", line 423, in open
  protocol = req.get_type()
File "urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type
  raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
```

So, my question is:

Is there a proper way to 'fix' those urls, or should I simply append `http://` in front of every string? I don't think that would be the best solution, because what about the urls that begin with `https://`?

Comment: Just prefix `http://`.  The there is a server that can talk HTTP to you, it will return `200 OK`. If it wants to talk HTTPS, it will redirect with a `301`.

Comment: All of the examples on this page show a "http://".   
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html
 Lutz is correct, check the HTTP status for a redirect.

Comment: You mean that if I get a `301`, I should then try `https://` ? Or it will redirect automatically?

Comment: @bmpasini, the `301` code means redirection. It's up to you to decide if you want to redirect (to request the page using `https://`) or not.

Comment: Really strictly speaking, those are not URLs at all. In many human contexts, you can leave off the protocol specifier part and still be understood, but without that sort of context, what you have is just a list of (apparent) server names, some or all of which might be running an HTTP server which responds to requests for that particular domain name. Of course, tacking on the `http://` prefix and trying is a good way to find out.

Comment: There is similarly no guarantee that a server which responds to HTTPS requests will also respond to HTTP requests, and if it does, there is no guarantee that the response will be a redirect, or in particular a redirect to the HTTPS server on the same host. Again, the only way to know is to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest just to append `http://` to the string as many sites that use the `https://` scheme switch to it automatically by redirecting the request.

You can check the status returned by `urlopen` using the `getcode()` function.

```
a=urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
print a.getcode() # prints 200
```